# absolute positioning disappears the element

Tags: html, css

I want a very thin horizontal line. (The result of the code below is exactly what I want)

The problem is If I want to set the `position` to `absolute` the line disappears?!

What I'm missing?

I've tried to change the position using margins but still...

```css
.nav-bar {
  /*position: absolute;*/
  border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(204,193,218,1);
  margin-top: 60vh;
  margin-left: 10vw;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head> 
</head>
<body> 
<div class="nav-bar">
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: you need to give at least a width after adding the position

Comment: That worked thanks... And why it works without width in the above code?

Comment: a div is block element and without position it will be full width by default

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're missing `width: 100%;`. `div` elements have this by default if they are normally positioned, but it needs to be manually set the you are using relative positioning.

At the moment, your line is being displayed with a width of 0, which is why you can't see it.

Also note: your `div` was missing a closing tag, I have fixed that in the code snippet below.

```css
.nav-bar {
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(204, 193, 218, 1);
  margin-top: 60vh;
  margin-left: 10vw;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="nav-bar">
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

Unless you specify either width or left/right positioning the element will be rendered with a width of 0. So you need to either write this

```
.nav-bar {
  position: absolute;
  left:0px;
  right: 0px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(204,193,218,1);
  margin-top: 60vh;
  margin-left: 10vw;
}
```

Or this

```
.nav-bar {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(204,193,218,1);
  margin-top: 60vh;
  margin-left: 10vw;
}
```

```css
.nav-bar {
  position: absolute;
  /*left:0px;
  right: 0px;*/
  border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(204,193,218,1);
  margin-top: 60vh;
  margin-left: 10vw;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head> 
</head>
<body> 
<div class="nav-bar"/>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

When you use `position: absolute`, you need to explicitly specify the element's width and height. And on a side note, your div does not have a closing tag.

```css
.nav-bar {
  position: absolute;
  border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(204,193,218,1);
  margin-top: 60vh;
  margin-left: 10vw;
  width:100%;
  height:50px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head> 
</head>
<body> 
<div class="nav-bar"> </div>
</body>
</html>
```